# How to adjust overlay according to image size with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create responsive images which can have different sizes. So far i am able to solve the common size issue with `max-height`, but the overlay is still a problem, hence it is filling the width of the column.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row team-images">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-item">
                <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-item">
                <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-item">
                <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-item">
                <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-item">
                <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-item">
                <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="team-item">
                <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.team-images .team-item {
    position: relative;
}
.team-images img {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}
.team-images .team-image-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.4);
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}
.team-images .team-image-overlay:hover {
    background: rgba(24, 188, 156, 0);
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/prp794Lb/5/

Comment: Remember the overlay is the size of the parent div. Your image is **not** because you have restricted the height..if you remove that it's fixed. - https://jsfiddle.net/prp794Lb/6/

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to run some javascript jQuery to dynamically resize each overlay after the DOM has been populated.

Comment: @PatDobson, so there wouldn't be any CSS trick to solve this?

Comment: As an alternative, wrap each image in **another** div and put the overlay on that.

Comment: @Paulie_D, that could be an option!

Comment: It's the only one I can think of. You need to shrink-wrap the image in something and overlay that.

Comment: JavaCake - probably, @Paulie_D seems to have one but it will involve more HTML markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/prp794Lb/7/)

```
.team-item {
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

This will solve your problem :)

Comment: Did the trick. But how would you build it instead of using the inline-block?

Comment: I mean the whole html structure, it's just my personal opinion, shouldn't say that though, don't take me wrong- your's is not bad, I have my own preferences, just it.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/prp794Lb/8/

This is a workaround with javascript. The only issue is that images have class image responsive that will make for images with 400x400 the overlay a little bigger.

```
$(".team-item").each(function(){
    var width = $(this).find("img").width();
    $(".team-image-overlay").width(width);
    var height = $(this).find("img").height();
    $(".team-image-overlay").height(height);
});
$( window ).resize(function() {
    $(".team-item").each(function(){
        var width = $(this).find("img").width();
        $(".team-image-overlay").width(width);
        var height = $(this).find("img").height();
        $(".team-image-overlay").height(height);
    });
});
```